# Inherite hub navigation in a hub to hub association

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, hub-site

I followed this guide (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hub-to-hub-association) to creaate a hub to hub association.

[image]

Taking this picture from the guide as an example for my problem: the hub navigation from the parent hub site (level 1 - blue) 'contoso marketing' is inherited to the associated child hub (level 2 - orange) 'south america marketing'.
The associated child hubs (level 3 - purple) inherit the hub navigation from there parent sites 'north america marketing' and 'asia marketing', but since this two are registered as hub sites, they do have their own hub navigation and do not inherit it from 'contoso marketing'.

My question/problem now is: I do have a hub navigation in the parent hub site, how can i achive  an inheritance of this navigation to *all* associated child hubs. Or in other words, i want to have the same hub navigation an every hub in this construction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Navigation inheritance is not the purpose of hub to hub association, as described in the documentation you referenced:

"Associate a SharePoint hub to another hub to expand search results across multiple hubs in your organization. This enables users to discover relevant content when searching on any sites related to the associated hubs."

If you would like the same navigation across many sites, then those sites should all be associated with the same hub.