# SPO Hub Sites - Should Navigation be displayed on Child Site(s)?

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I have contacted MS on this issue and I am even more confused now.

I have a SPO site contoso.sharepoint.com which is where I have our intranet.
I created contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/corporate and in Admin Center registered it as a Hub Site.
Parent Hub Association is Contoso.

When I go to contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/corporate I don't see the navigation from the parent (Contoso)

Should I?

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [support documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca#hubnav):

> Note: It may take up to two hours for changes to the hub site navigation bar to appear on associated sites.

Also, what is the type of the sub site (communication site with modern experience)?

What is the response from Microsoft when you submitted your issue?

Note that the hub navigation shared across hub sites is a different from the parent hub site navigation. It's two different data sources. If you want to add links in the hub navigation already existing in the parent site, you have to recreate them again. There is no synchronization between navigation and hub navigation.

Related questions:

- [Inherite hub navigation in a hub to hub association](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302943/inherite-hub-navigation-in-a-hub-to-hub-association)
- [Removing Hub Navigation on SharePoint Online modern pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300999/removing-hub-navigation-on-sharepoint-online-modern-pages?rq=1)

Comment: OK thanks. I associated them weeks ago.

Comment: They are Comms sites with Modern Exp. MS say that the navigation from the parent site shouldn't appear on the child site. But I thought it should. Does it for you?

Comment: MS "in order for you to have the same tabs you have on your Home site to your sub sites, you will need to recreate them again"

Comment: OK. I agree with Microsoft. You will not have the parent navigation links to the child site.

Comment: But the support documentation states "It may take up to two hours for changes to the hub site navigation bar to appear on associated sites."

Comment: Yes, the navigation bar. So you can customize it and add links. But the links from the parent site will never be synchronized here. That's why you "can recreate them" if you want.

Comment: This question sees to say it's possible? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302943/inherite-hub-navigation-in-a-hub-to-hub-association

Comment: Yes, but you don't understand that the links shared within the hub are custom links you have to define (cf. Microsoft answer), not the current links from the parent hub site. Every site has its own navigation (vertical or horizontal) and the shared navigation (horizontal on top). It's two different navigations.

Comment: I have sites that are not registered as hub sites that are associated to the parent hub. All of them show the parent hubs navigation. However it is the Corporate site (which itself is registered as a Hub) that will not show it's parents navigation.